# Implementation of the NServiceBus/MassTransit IContainer with DryIoc or LightInject

Tags: nservicebus, masstransit, light-inject, dryioc

I had used DryIoc and LightInject in most of my .Net Web API 2+ solutions. Using new architecture, I would prefer to use NServiceBus or MassTransit for my next ESB implementation. However, I could not find any useful code reference that could help me to do Implementation of the NServiceBus/MassTransit IContainer with DryIoc or LightInject. Other IoC is not an option for me as the requirement from my company is to choose only from both of the above mentioned. Greatly appreciate any help from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will [this help?](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers/#plugging-in-your-own-container) "If you have your own container that is not already supported by a NuGet package, you can create a plugin centering around the IContainer abstraction. Once this is created and registered, NServiceBus will use your custom container to look up its own dependencies."

Comment: Sean, thanks. I had made my decision to use [rebus 2](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus), as it has the container adapter for light inject. At least the performance is close to DryIoc. I had came across the link that you gave me. Still I found that it is not helpful. They should demonstrate further as the element of using container is very important on the implementation their ESB framework.